# Rails & Oauth: multiple providers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've got an app that permits users to post to LinkedIn, Facebook, and Twitter. I'd like to authorise each user's account with as many of those providers as the user would like.

My user model has some columns to help authorise one provider at a time:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :oauth_token, :oauth_expires_at, :oauth_token_secret, :access_token, :access_token_secret ...
  ...
end
```

Here's the model method:

```
def self.from_omniauth(user, auth)
  user.provider = auth.provider
  if auth.provider == "facebook"
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
    user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  elsif auth.provider == "twitter"
    # not sure which one twitter uses
    user.oauth_token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
    user.oauth_token_secret = auth["credentials"]["secret"]
    user.access_token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
    user.access_token_secret = auth["credentials"]["secret"]
  end
  user.save!
end
```

And the controller auth method looks like this:

```
def authorise
  user = User.from_omniauth(current_user, env['omniauth.auth'])
  session[:user_id] = current_user.id
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Any help would be great! Really not sure how to proceed from here. Having x (3 in the above case, more to come) amount of `:provider` columns seems kinda ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to separate out the authentication piece from the User model itself, that way you can do a `has_many` relationship between users and identities.  Here's my `Identity` model from an old project (using omniauth):

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessible :provider, :uid,
                  :description, :email, :first_name, :image,
                  :last_name, :location, :name, :nickname,
                  :phone, :raw_info, :urls

  validates_presence_of :provider, :uid
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, scope: :provider

  def self.find_with_omniauth(auth)
    find_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
  end

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create(provider:      auth['provider'],
            uid:          auth['uid'],
            name:         auth['info']['name'],
            email:        auth['info']['email'],
            nickname:     auth['info']['nickname'],
            first_name:   auth['info']['first_name'],
            last_name:    auth['info']['last_name'],
            location:     auth['info']['location'],
            description:  auth['info']['description'],
            image:        auth['info']['image'],
            phone:        auth['info']['phone'],
            urls:         auth['info']['urls'].to_json,
            raw_info:     auth['extra']['raw_info'].to_json
          )
  end
end
```

And then of course the User model should reference that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy
  ...
```

There are a lot of pesky edge cases when you're allowing multiple omniauth providers for login.  So to create a new login (session), you can do something like:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    origin = request.env['omniauth.origin']
    destination = origin.blank? ? root_path : origin
    @identity = Identity.find_with_omniauth(auth)
    @identity = Identity.create_with_omniauth(auth) if @identity.nil?

    if signed_in?
      if @identity.user == current_user
        # Identity is already associated with this user
        redirect_to destination, notice: "Already logged in and linked"
      else
        # Identity is not associated with the current_user
        @old_user = @identity.user
        if @old_user
          current_user.posts << @old_user.posts
          current_user.galleries << @old_user.galleries
          current_user.favorites << @old_user.favorites
        end
        @identity.user = current_user
        @identity.save()
        @old_user.destroy if @old_user && @old_user.identities.blank?
        redirect_to destination, notice: "Account was successfully linked"
      end
    else
      if @identity.user.present?
        # Identity has a user associated with it
        self.current_user = @identity.user
        redirect_to destination
      else
        # No user associated with the identity so create a new one
        user = User.create_with_omniauth(auth['info'])
        @identity.user = user
        @identity.save()
        self.current_user = @identity.user
        redirect_to destination, notice: "Registration successful"
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    self.current_user = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed out successfully"
  end

  def omniauth_failure
    origin = request.env['omniauth.origin']
    destination = origin.blank? ? root_path : origin
    redirect_to destination, alert: "Connection failed"
  end
end
```

As I recall, I leaned on an article about this topic written a while back when I was writing the code above.  See https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Managing-Multiple-Providers for more info & ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your really in-depth answer! Looking forward to checkin' in out.

Comment: My interpretation of this came out pretty different, but thanks for the ideas.

Comment: You didn't address what to do with the tokens.

Comment: Very good solution. I personally found this article http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/ to be the only one that actually worked from start to finish. The approach is different from the solution in that it doesn't use creating/destroying Identities as logins. It leaves them there permanently, and using the information to log in via devise. Thus you're still logging in the same way, which makes for fewer different cases.

Comment: The real plus of this method is that it redirects twitter users to fill in their email or password the first time, making the headache of twitter not giving you an email go away with a clean, thorough solution.